Determiners vs adjectives


I booked a single room.
I gave double the price.


Are 'both single and double' considered as determiners?
Here both are multiplicative numerals. So, I think both are determiners.
But I have seen in Cambridge dictionary that 'single' is considered as an adjective.
And I mostly follow traditional grammars. So, please show me the differences between traditional and modern grammars here.

In example 1, "a" is the determiner.  If the "a" were omitted, the sentence would be incomplete.  So we have two ways of knowing that "single" is not a determiner in this sentence.
In example 2, "the" is the determiner.  If the "the" were omitted, the meaning would change.  Instead of the price being double a previously mentioned price, the price would be double an unmentioned typical price.  So we have two ways of knowing that "double" is not a determiner in this sentence.

Can I get references on this topic?

+1 but would be better with fully written out examples!
